# Javascript object structure difference

Tags: javascript, object

Can you explain me what is the difference between these two objects? How can I add word 'Product' at the beginning of the object?

```
Array(2)
0: {status: "published", _id: "5ff584e56153e75706790fa9", title: "bbbbb", imageUrl: "images/2021-01-06T11:59:42.006Z-7pIfYwyRCL8.jpg", price: 3333111, …}

1: Product {_id: "5ff58d1c6153e75706790faa", title: "5555555", imageUrl: "images/2021-01-06T11:30:26.521Z-7pIfYwyRCL8.jpg", description: "sddsdsd", price: 3333, …}length: 2
```

Also, the image:
[image]

Comment: Why does it matter? --- `Product` is likely to be made using a constructor function or a class. The other is likely to be a "plain" object.

Comment: Hi , you can use object of objects :like this
data ={Product::{...yourData}}. and you access and updated edit like this :
data.Product and do whats ever you want

Answer (score 2):

Thats because this second one was most likely created using

```js
const product = new Product(...)
```

while first one

```js
const product = {...}
```

And so the type doesn't match

It's similar to this case

```js
const someMap = new Map();
someMap.set("hello", "world");

const someObject = {
    hello: "world",
}

someMap == someObject // false
someMap === someObject // false
```

Comment: I’m curious, what type? They’re both objects?

Comment: @evolutionxbox first one is instance of Product, second one is instance of Object

Comment: Yeah, both objects are indead objects and have the type object.

Comment: It is things like the `.__proto__` that will be different, not the type

Comment: @GrzegorzBarański Product is an object not a type?

Comment: product is instace of Product, so its different than Object, as @TheOtterlord said, check the `.__proto__` on both of those things, they will be different

Comment: @GrzegorzBarański I think the problem is that you say the type doesn't match, but if you use `typeof` the types are the same (`object`)

Comment: Oh right, I meant that they're different instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `Product` prefix shows that it is an instance of a class `Product`, while the first object is a normal JavaScript object.

We can use `instanceof` to determine if an object is an instance of a class.

```js
class Product {
    constructor() {}
}

const product = new Product()

// product
console.log(product instanceof Product); // true
// empty object
console.log({} instanceof Product); // false
```